# What to use to get typeof(Enum)

Tags: c#, enums

I have created an Enum which looks as under

```
namespace MyNamespace.something
{
   public enum FuncResultCode
   {
      SUCCESS,
      MISSING_INFO,
      UNALLOWED_CHANGES
   }
}
```

When i use `typeof` on this Enum, I get below error

```
Console.WriteLine(" " + typeof(FuncResultCode))
```

> Error 84  The type or namespace name 'FuncResultCode' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Should typeof(Enum) not be used for Enums ? If not, then what else to use ?**

Comment: _Should typeof(Enum) not be used for Enums?_ Based on error message, that's not the case. Where did you write this `typeof(FuncResultCode)` exactly? Did you add relevant (`MyNamespace.something`) namespace to that class?

Comment: yes, I added `MySpace.something` and I added in `Console.WriteLine`

Comment: Indeed - basically the error message is saying exactly what you should check...

Comment: @SimpleGuy: No, the point is that you should have `using MyNamespace.something` in the code which is trying to use `typeof(FuncResultCode)`. If you could show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem, that would hlep - I suspect that in trying to produce that, you'll find the problem. Btw, conventionally enums in .NET have PascalCased values, e.g. Success, MissingInfo, UnallowedChanges.

Comment: BTW VS Intellisense is detecting it too and i have added a nsamespace also. That namespace was already present, there are several things used from that namespace

Comment: @JonSkeet. Good suggestion. let me make a small program

Comment: next time you need an enum give this post a chance... https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/12/enumeration-classes/

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine, I wrote a very small code and its working properly.

```
using MyNamespace.something;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" " + typeof(FuncResultCode));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

```
namespace MyNamespace.something
{
public enum FuncResultCode
{
    SUCCESS,
    MISSING_INFO,
    UNALLOWED_CHANGES
 }
}
```

And output is as expected:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Let me check mine

Comment: This answer does in no way explain why the OP gets the error message he gets. Yes, the code as posted should work, but there's another reason for the error message, the enum is not there. It is probably located in a project/assembly that is not referenced.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen To solve any problem you could choose either way: 1. Find it why it is not working. 2. Show what is working. I chose the second one. Also, by seeing this code, he can find out what is wrong with his code. And about the details of error message, you are right. I don't know why he is getting that error.